# Generic BubbleSort Extension

Tags: c#, generics

```
    public static T[] BubbleSort<T>(this T[] arr) where T : class
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length-1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j])
                    swap(arr[j - 1], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I create a generic bubble sort extension method? Is there any way to handle the comparing here ?
Error   1   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Comment: What are you asking here? It certainly looks like you've created an extension method. Perhaps you just want to make sure `T` implements `IComparable`?

Comment: it does not work. Error 1 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Comment: I think the OP wants an implementation to compare classes, as opposed to `x > y`, but its unclear.

Comment: More importantly, why would you ever want bubblesort? It's basically the worst.

Comment: @John If you change the outer loop to terminate once nothing changed it can be efficient in scenarios where not much changes. But still that's a rare special purpose choice.

Comment: @John: Maybe it's just some programming practice. Starting off with implementing all kinds of sorting algorithms is not uncommon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can restrict `T` to `IComparable<T>` like this:

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(this T[] arr) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length-1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j].CompareTo(arr[j + 1]) > 0)
                swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

which has the advantage that T can also be a value type like `int`. Also your function does not need to return the array as it changes the `this` array.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `<` on type parameters.
So you could use `Comparer<T>.Default`.

Or you could just add a generic contraint that requires `T` to implement `IComparable<T>`. Then you can call the `Compare` method.

In addition your `j` loop is off by one. You either need to compare&swap arr[j] and arr[j+1] or change the lower bound to `1` and the upper to `arr.Length`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways you could go about doing this:

1. Require T to implement `IComparable<T>` and use the `CompareTo` method to do comparisons.
2. Add a second parameter of type `IComparer<T>` that implements a custom comparison. You would then use this comparer object to do key comparisons.