# How can i make this code re-usable?

Tags: c#, methods

i currently have a bubble sort method (shown below) but i was unsure on how to modify it to be re-usable so instead of there being only the variable arri can simply insert a new array every time i call the method instead of repeating the same code? Thank you

```
static void bsort(float[] arr)
    {

        float temp = 0;

        for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++)
        {
            for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++)
            {
                if (arr[sort] < arr[sort + 1])
                {
                    temp = arr[sort + 1];
                    arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
                    arr[sort] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) ;
    }
```

Comment: so you don't know whether it is a float array, double or an int and so on? look up for template functions

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to sort arrays of types other than `float`?  If so then you'll want to use generics.

Comment: What exactly does `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) ;` do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IComparable<T>` as explained in this thread

[Generic BubbleSort Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783852/generic-bubblesort-extension)

like this...

```
 public static void BubbleSort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable
        {
            for (int outer = array.Length; outer >= 1; outer--)
            {
                for (int inner = 0; inner < outer - 1; inner++)
                {
                    if (array[inner].CompareTo(array[inner + 1]) > 0)
                    {
                        T swap = array[inner];
                        array[inner] = array[inner + 1];
                        array[inner + 1] = swap;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: While the link might answer the question you should include the relevant information here and only use the link for reference.

Comment: @juharr That, or mark this question as a duplicate of the referenced original.

Comment: @fvu Yeah, I didn't even click it to see that it's just another SO question.

Comment: One more easy solution is to use dynamic key word.So your function would be  static void bsort(dynamic arr) { }
No matter what type you pass, it works and its reusable